# Error when Using Custom React Hook in a Multi-Module Project for Tests with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hooks

I'm having a project with multiple Webpack modules. In my child module, I want to create a custom React hook, which I can use in React components in the parent module.

My example hook is quite simple:

```js
export function useTitle(title: string): void {
    useEffect(() => {
        document.title = title
    }, [title]);
}
```

However, when using my custom hook in a React component outside of the module, I get an error:

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

I assume that the cause is that a React instance is created for each Webpack module. A Jest test comparing the React instance of the child module with the one of the parent module also shows this.

```js
import {react} from "child-module";

test("react instance", () => {
    expect(react).toBe(React); // serializes to the same string, but unequal
});
```

Is there anyway to use a custom React hook from one Webpack module in another without getting an error?

**What I have already tried without any success**

- In my Webpack config files, I set external declarations for React to avoid that React will be included in the output Webpack bundles.
- In the package.json of the child module, I have declare React as peer dependency.
- In the package.json of the parent module, I have linked to the React installation of the child-module: `"react": "../child-module/node_modules/react"` to ensure that both modules use the same React copy.
- On runtime, I make it working my delivering React from a CDN and not from any Webpack module. However, it doesn't help me much if I cannot test my React components.

Comment: Please see [this](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html#duplicate-react) and [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could finally solve the issue by storing React in the node_modules folder of the common root folder of the child and parent module.

My project structure:

```
project
|
+--- node_modules     <-- React is here
|
+--+ child-module
|  |
|  +--- node_modules  <-- Does NOT contain React
|
+--+ parent-module
   |
   +--- node_modules  <-- Does NOT contain React
```